# Getting error for 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used a code like this below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["tx"]) == false)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["tx"]), "[^a-zA-Z0-9 %  +]"))
            {
                //error
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                SearchResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting error at

*if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["tx"]) == false)*

as  **'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'**

Also, I have used the related namespace also.

And I am using asp.net version 2.0 and cannot change. Please help what needs to be done to resolve this issue

Comment: You can use IsNullOrEmpty first and then check for whitespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was introduced in .NET 4.0:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you really can't use a later version, then you could build your own method to do the same thing.

Here is the implementation of that method (thanks Farhad Jabiyev):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (value == null) return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
        if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note: I have removed the `[Pure]` attribute which is present in the implementation at the above link because `System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute` [is also not present until .NET 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Here is the implemetation: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef

You can add this to your answer.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev -- Thanks, I was trying to look that up but am on a spotty connection :)  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NadeemKhan -- try adding `System.Diagnostics.Contracts`.

Comment: @NadeemKhan -- That must be a later version thing too.  Just delete `[Pure]` altogether then.

Comment: OK, i will update you once the code has been updated to the production server

Comment: @NadeemKhan Why did you post a link to a bank?  What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: @roryap : just wanted to let u know what was the actual error. Deleted that comment. And your answer was nearer to my solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`:

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string input)
{
    if (input == null || input == String.Empty) return true;
    foreach (char c in input)
        if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the explanation. How should I render in my code

Comment: @NadeemKhan: you just need to copy-paste above method into a class that is accessible from where you need it.

Comment: Sure, will do the same and check.

Comment: Any other suggestion, why i am getting the same error even after applying the method. ??

Answer (score 0):

You can check like:

```
if (Request.QueryString["tx"] != null && Request.QueryString["tx"].Trim() != "")
```

Answer (score -1):

As roryap says, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is not available.

`String.IsNullOrEmpty` is though, which may suit your needs.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["tx"]))
```

Comment: Will check this and let you know.. :)

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` is not the same as `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, so if OP needs the functionality of the latter method he has to build a custom method anyway.

Comment: Agreed; I did say "may suit your needs" not "will work as an exact replacement".